# Crispy-forms InlineRadios don't show my model state

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

Weird, I have a model with a Charfield that has some possible values

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="We will refer to your entry by this title.")
    production_type = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        max_length=32,
        default=None,
        choices=  (('Agency', 'Agency'),('Brand', 'Brand'),))
```

When I render a simple ModelForm

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = [
            'title', 'production_type'
        ]
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'title',
            'production_type'
        )
```

It renders a dropdown for the production_type fields with the correct state chosen. If I add the InlineRadios widget as below, the radio buttons don't pick up the model state when rendered. I always get the first choice. The form submits fine.

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = [
            'title', 'production_type'
        ]
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'title',
             InlineRadios('production_type', css_class='production_type_holder')
        )
```

Any way to get **both** the inline radio button behavior and to have my model state tracked?

Comment: Please provide template for your form, 
... would be good to see views.py too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to have been a false alarm. My designer radically changed the css in a way that breaks crispy forms. I thought I had isolated the changes, but once I removed all the application generated CSS all worked well.  Sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

There may be few errors:

1. `EntryForm` has line  `model = Entry`, instead must be `model = Payment` , as in model you describe `Payment`
2. In `EntryForm.__init__` lack of line `super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`
3. your `__init__` declaration contain redundant(?) parameter `request` so declaration must be

   ```
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): #without request
   ```

Please try this changes.

Your code(in my edition, below) works ok with normal behaviour of radio buttons, it normally creates new payment and prints existing.

models.py without changes

forms.py

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field, Fieldset, ButtonHolder, Submit
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import InlineRadios

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Payment # !not Entry
        fields = [
            'title', 'production_type'
        ]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  #!without request
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  #this line present
        self.helper = FormHelper()

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'title',
            InlineRadios('production_type'),
            Submit('submit', 'Submit'), # i miss your submit button, so adding here
        )
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


# it creates new payment 
class PaymentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Payment
    form_class= EntryForm
    template_name='payment_form.html'
    success_url = '/payment/'

# this usual view just print form with already created instance
def PaymentView (request):
    form =  EntryForm(instance = Payment.objects.get(id=4))
    c = {'form': form}
    return render(request,'payment_form.html', c)
```

payment_form.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}

</body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```
...
#i made 2 views, one for 'usual' view, one for generic view
url(r'payment_view/', PaymentView), 
url(r'payment/', PaymentCreate.as_view()),
...
```

Comment: That's for your help, but the incorrect model was just a transcription error. I will try removing the request from the form, though I'm not very hopeful.

Comment: The main point is do not miss to call parent __init__ method and remove request

Comment: Thanks.  I'm calling the super constructor as well. I'll change the request thing. Also I'll make one last check to make sure no javascript or css is affecting this.

Comment: Also theres' no problem with having the request as the first parameter of my constructor, as long as  *args, **kwargs   follow.  I will look again at the js and css and then will hack it :)